# mousebind and scrollTo

Tags: javascript, scroll

I would like to bind a „mouse scroll“ to a “scrollTo“ event – when I scroll down, the link with id „next“ should bring me to next div.

```
<a id="next" href="#">Next</a>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at this jQuery plugin, [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/).

Comment: Thank you, this online looks good: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/scrollto-demo/

But how can I bind this to mouse scroll down event?